# NLog Logger takes a long time to load when debugging a unit test on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nlog

When I debug a unit test on Visual Studio 2013 the line of code where the NLog Logger is created:

> > private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

Takes at least 35 seconds to return. I'm using the NLog Nuget package version 2.0.1.2. I didn't have that behavior with VS2012.
Has anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for the answer @JaredPar. I figured out the problem. In the app.config I had this in the nlog xml element:

> > nlog internalLogFile="c:\log.txt" internalLogLevel="Trace" xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"

As soon as I removed the internal logging attributes everything worked fine:

> > nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"

Answer (score 1):

Note that the implementation of `GetCurrentClassLogger` specifically notes that this can be a slow running method

```
<remarks>This is a slow-running method. Make sure you're not doing this in a loop.</remarks>
```

A time of 35 seconds does seem a bit extreme.  But it's probably not completely out of range given that it's doing a bit of stack walking.

Instead of using that method you may want to change your code to use one of the faster methods of creating a logger.  Perhaps the `GetLogger(string name)` overload